# В windows 10 отключается wi-fi

Tags: windows, wifi

Установил Windows 10, и есть проблемы, постояно отключается wi-fi, приходиться запускать программу по устранению неполадок сети, особено отключается когда запускаю игру world of tanks. Настройки энергосбережения настроил, так чтоб не отключался wi-fi адаптер. Драйвера Broadcom установлены самые новые, роутер в испровноам состоянии, ноут Lenovo g780. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Дрова откуда брал? С сайта Леновы, с сайта Броадком, с дрп.су?

Comment: Дрова нигде не брал windows 10 сама при установке всё установила. В диспетчере устройств кликаю на броадком - обновить драйвер, система пишет что установлен самый актуальный драйвер

Comment: Не знаю что делать, если не получется решить проблему, придётся устанавить windows 7 тогда.

Comment: А с сайта леновы не пробовал?

Comment: пробовал но от туда не устанваливаются на windows 10, там для 7 и 8.1

Comment: По `id` на `drp.su` пробовал искать?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь я понял в чём дело, проблема в драйверах, драйвера wi-fi нужны те которые на сайте Lenovo, а не от производителя wi-fi карты Broadcom, но там нет для 10, только для 7 и 8 винды, пробовал их устанавливать, они не устанавливаются. Не стал возиться с драйверами, установил windows 7, сейчас сижу и всё работает без проблем.